Weighted least squares vs log transform
I'm sure that I'm going to get somebody annoyed by my lack of research on this question, but I'm not good enough at statistics to know where to go to do the research effectively, so please try to bear with me. Also this is a long question.
DATA:
I have obtained some experimental data from an analytical chemistry instrument which look like this (see the end of the question for context if you are interested):
Concentration (microgram analyte per gram solution): [0.001, 0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1.0,5.0,10.0]
Instrument response: [0.01268957104309631, 0.0620294717767042, 0.12539584223826, 0.6248445517623655, 1.1899660451682297, 5.497336533886023, 10.984401515120192, 54.763562330887666, 109.94166085424847]

STATISTICS:
Here is the meat of my question. I have been interpreting these data by a logarithmic transform. Essentially I have been performing a linear regression on log(Instrument response) (X) vs. log(Concentration) (y) in order to predict the concentrations of experimental samples based on instrument response.
Basically, I am regressing
$$ \ln y_i = \alpha \ln x_i + \beta $$
and assuming the intercept in the original equation $y = mx + b$ goes to zero, which is very nearly true. Then I calculate
$$ \hat{y_i} = \exp \left( \alpha \ln \hat{x_i} + \beta \right) $$
to predict $\hat{y_i}$ for future measurements $\hat{x_i}$.
I did this because I want to weight each point equally in the calibration and get approximately equal relative residuals across the concentration range; however, I have been advised by a professor on my graduate committee that this is not a statistically valid approach, as the standard linear regression formula assumes equal variances for all the error terms, and this cannot simultaneously be true for the raw data and the log-transformed data. He tells me that even if I am not assuming equal variances for errors, but rather variances proportional to the expected concentrations (which can vary over orders of magnitude), I should be doing weighted least-squares regression instead.
The issue I am having, and the heart of my question, is that in spite of the fact that I can't argue with this professor on theoretical grounds, my method of analysis just seems to fit the data better than weighted least squares. I am wondering why that is the case or if I am just wrong.
The Julia code at the end of this question is self-contained and produces several plots which I hope will illustrate what I mean, and include analysis by vanilla OLS for comparison (see below). Using weighted least squares where I weight by the inverse square of the expected concentration, I get residuals that appear to be normally distributed about zero. However, they are strictly worse than the residuals I get from the log-transformed calculation:
$$ RR = \frac{(y_i - \hat{y_i})}{y_i} $$
Relative Residuals
Weighted least squares: [0.017574548681706423, -0.045990240330834146, -0.06849741392550411, -0.07362065130526979, -0.02330666221187383, 0.05372116144036787, 0.054495426858348406, 0.05713545744282076, 0.053555840071817684]
Log-transform:          [0.01626727991092488, 0.007682238292841537, -0.017032940658855134, -0.04619063044526306, -0.008930672902318637, 0.0392338321005008, 0.026936557118281024, -0.0014928906219523696, -0.01919719116055383]


PICTURES:
Error/fit plots for weighted least squares

Error/fit plots for the log-transform fit

Plot of predicted values using for different fits

Plot of relative residuals for all fits

What is going on here? I wish I could put the question better than that, but I'm just not that good at statistics...
CONTEXT:
In the course of graduate work in chemistry/chemical engineering, I have made a series of logarithmically spaced standard solutions for use in calibrating the response of an analytical chemistry instrument called ICP-MS. Essentially this is a way to get the elemental composition of a liquid sample.
The data as I present them here have been corrected by something called an internal standard, further description of which is out of scope of this question, but which I include as a note to anyone reading this who knows what ICP-MS raw data look like and is confused by the numbers given here.
CODE:
The Julia code below, partially taken with edits from the docs of LinearRegressionKit.jl is sufficient to produce several error plots and all the data in this question. Sorry, I am not familiar enough with R to do this in R.

using StatsModels, DataFrames, LinearRegressionKit, CairoMakie, VegaLite
mypredict(linreg, xs) = xs .* linreg.coefs[2] .+ linreg.coefs[1]

function main()
    mydf = DataFrame(conc = [0.001, 0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1.0,5.0,10.0],
    counts = [10929.96
       53201.83
       106729.92
       487340.06
       947698.49
       4601392.17
       9298663.86
       43333650.04
       87516369.95
       ],
       istdcounts = [861334.08
       857686.33
       851144.01
       779938.08
       796408.01
       837022.1
       846533.5
       791286.18
       796025.54
       ])
    mydf[!,"istdcorrected"] = mydf[!, :counts] ./ mydf[!, :istdcounts]
    mydf[!,"weights"] = 1.0 ./ (mydf[!, :conc] .^ 2)
    myf = @formula(conc ~ istdcorrected)
    lms, pss = regress(myf, mydf, "all", 
    req_stats=["default", "vif", "AIC"], 
    plot_args=Dict("plot_width" => 200))
    println(lms)
    println(lms.coefs)
    lmw, psw = regress(myf, mydf, "all", weights="weights", 
    req_stats=["default", "vif", "AIC"], 
    plot_args=Dict("plot_width" => 200))
    println(lmw)
    [[pss["fit"] pss["residuals"]]
    [pss["histogram density"] pss["qq plot"]]] |> save("errplotsOLS.png")
    [[psw["fit"] psw["residuals"]]
    [psw["histogram density"] psw["qq plot"]]] |> save("errplotsWLS.png")

    mydf[!,"logconc"] = log.(mydf[!,:conc])
    mydf[!, "logistdcorrected"] = log.(mydf[!,:istdcorrected])
    
    myf2 = @formula(logconc ~ logistdcorrected)
    loglms, logpss = regress(myf2, mydf, "all", 
    req_stats=["default", "vif", "AIC"], 
    plot_args=Dict("plot_width" => 200))
    println(loglms)

    [[logpss["fit"] logpss["residuals"]]
    [logpss["histogram density"] logpss["qq plot"]]] |> save("errplotslogOLS.png")

    mydf[!,"predictOLS"] = mypredict(lms, mydf[!,:istdcorrected])
    mydf[!,"predictWLS"] = mypredict(lmw, mydf[!,:istdcorrected])
    mydf[!,"predictLOG"] = exp.(mypredict(loglms, mydf[!, :logistdcorrected]))
    mydf[!,"relerrOLS"] = (mydf[!, :conc] .- mydf[!,"predictOLS"]) ./ mydf[!, :conc]
    mydf[!,"relerrWLS"] = (mydf[!, :conc] .- mydf[!,"predictWLS"]) ./ mydf[!, :conc]
    mydf[!,"relerrLOG"] = (mydf[!, :conc] .- mydf[!,"predictLOG"]) ./ mydf[!, :conc]
    mydf[!,"pnum"] = collect(1:length(mydf[!,:conc]))

    #mydf |> @vlplot(width=400,height=400, color={field="symbol",scale={range=["black","red","green"]}}) + 
    #@vlplot(mark={:point, color=:red}, data=mydf, x=:pnum, y=:relerrOLS) + 
    #@vlplot(mark={:point, color=:black}, data=mydf, x=:pnum, y=:relerrWLS) + 
    #@vlplot(mark={:point, color=:green}, data=mydf, x=:pnum, y=:relerrLOG) |> save("relerrs.png")

    f = Figure()
    ax = Axis(f[1, 1],
    title = "Different Linear Regression Methods",
    xlabel = "Counts 89Y / Counts 90Zr",
    ylabel = "Concentration (micrograms Y/mL)")
    scatter!(ax, mydf[!,"istdcorrected"], mydf[!, :conc], label="Data")

    lines!(ax, mydf[!,"istdcorrected"], mydf[!,"predictOLS"], label="OLS")
    lines!(ax, mydf[!,"istdcorrected"], mydf[!,"predictWLS"], label="WLS")
    lines!(ax, mydf[!,"istdcorrected"], mydf[!,"predictLOG"], label="Log-log OLS")

    f[1, 2] = Legend(f, ax, "Analysis Method", framevisible = false)
    save("RegressionComparison.png",f)
    f2 = Figure()
    ax2 = Axis(f2[1, 1],
    title = "Relative Residuals of Different Linear Regression Methods",
    xlabel = "Counts 89Y / Counts 90Zr",
    ylabel = "Relative Error in Concentration (micrograms Y/g -- 0.01 is 1%)")
    ylims!(ax2, -0.2,0.2)
    scatter!(ax2, mydf[!,"relerrOLS"], label="OLS")
    scatter!(ax2, mydf[!,"relerrWLS"], label="WLS")
    scatter!(ax2, mydf[!,"relerrLOG"], label="Log-log OLS")
    #scatter!(ax2, residuals2 ./ conc, label = "Log-log")
    #xlabel
    f2[1, 2] = Legend(f2, ax2, "Analysis Method", framevisible = false)
    save("ResidualsComparison.png", f2)
    println(mydf[!, :istdcorrected])
end

main()



Have you tried weighted least squares on the log-transformed data? That might give you the best of both approaches: a first pass at stabilizing variance with the log transform, then accounting for further heteroscedasticity with weighted least squares.

I am satisfied with the results I get from my current approach, so I am not really looking to improve it, but it seems to need some defense on theoretical grounds. I am not sure why the log transform stabilizes variance, as you put it. Any pointers to aid my understanding here would be helpful.

The problem with just doing the log transform is as the professor stated. If you don't have constant error variance (known as homoscedasticity) in the log scale as a function of the actual values, then an important assumption for ordinary least squares doesn't hold for your model. Weighted least squares is a way to deal with heteoscedasticity. Even if the point estimates from the model don't change much, the standard errors should be more reliable.

Ah, after rereading your comments it makes sense. In the log domain I no longer have any clue what the weights should look like, but I guess that is a completely separate question, so I will try to find out and ask another question if stumped.

This answer provides a hint, for your situation where you don't have replicates at each concentration: "you could estimate $\sigma^2(\mu)$ as a function of the fitted $\mu$ and use $w_i=1/\sigma^2(\mu_i)$." You might do that by plotting squared residuals from the initial least squares fit in the log-transformed scale and estimating a smooth association. Things are often simpler (and typically more reliable) when you have replicates for each condition and thus can estimate the variance more directly.

To start, you should not be "performing a linear regression on log(Instrument response) (X) vs. log(Concentration) (y)." Linear regression assumes that the X values are known and that errors are in the Y observations. For calibration curves you should do the regression in the other direction and then apply principles of inverse prediction to get concentration estimates (with associated errors) from instrument values.
Even when you do that, however, the issues raised by the professor on your committee still need to be addressed. The main point is that the assumption of homoscedasticity, constant variance of errors over the range of outcome values, is important for ordinary least squares. The professor is correct in two respects: (1) that assumption won't hold in both the original and log-transformed scales, and (2) if you don't have adequate homoscedasticity then weighted least squares is a way to correct for heteroscedasticity.
Each of those points, however, requires further consideration.
First, log transforms can go far toward providing homoscedastic errors in this type of data, as you demonstrated.
There's no requirement that you perform regressions in the original scale of measurements. You can still work in the log-log scale even if the intercept isn't 0 in the original scale provided that you model the predictor values flexibly, for example with a regression spline, instead of strictly linearly. More broadly, you should know that there is a whole family of generalized linear models designed to model specific transformations of outcome values as linear functions of predictors.
Second, using weighted least squares to correct for heteroscedasticity assumes that the observation weights (inverses of error variances) are known. A feasible generalized least squares method can used when the weights aren't known, but it can be unstable with small numbers of observations as you have here. This answer suggests developing a model of variance as a function of mean as an alternative. That might not be very accurate with this small number of observations. There might be a way to combine information from multiple instrument runs and samples, or to use the known characteristics of the instrument, to improve such a model.
To address the concerns of your professor, you might consider working in the log-transformed scale as a (very big) start toward stabilizing the error variance over the range of observations and then doing weighted least squares in that scale. I played with your data a bit in several ways (via regression in the direction that I suggest rather than yours) and didn't find much improvement over your simple log model, but the professor might have further suggestions.

Just a clarification on OLS: The parameters estimated by OLS are consistently estimated even if the variance is misspecified, for example, because of heteroscedasticity. (Only the standard errors need to be corrected by e.g. using heteroscedasticity robust Huber-White standard errors). WLS can improve efficiency if the variance is known or can be reasonably well estimated which might be difficult in small samples. (If the variance function is misspecified in WLS, then the parameter estimates are consistent but the standard errors are still wrong, same as in OLS.)
